# Keeping a build process running after Jenkins job

Tags: apache, jenkins, configuration

I am trying to keep a web process running after the *Jenkins* job is done.

I looked into *ProcessTreeKiller* and have tried using `BuildId` as below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /usr/apache/bin/httpd
```

My command (which I want to keep it running):

```
rails s &
```

How can I fix this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You put that into your **Execute Shell** build step, not as a jenkins build process variable (which is what you did with EnvInject plugin in your screenshot)

So, if you are trying to run `rails &`, then do:
`BUILD_ID=dontKillMe rails &`

Comment: i tried adding 'BUILD_ID=dontKillMe node app.js" before the line "node app.js" but i didn't work :(

Comment: @johnlowvale not sure if typo or not, but did you include ` &` at the end?

Comment: it still doesn't work, so i moved to use 'forever' and 'pm2' for my nodejs server

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
(
  set -e
  export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
  export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe
  rails &
) &
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the last stage in your Jenkinsfile, (like my case), you can use `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` to solve that problem, like this:

```
stage("Run"){
  steps{
    withEnv(['BUILD_ID=dontKillMe']) {
      script{
        sh '<YOUR COMMAND HERE>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, I have Jenkins in Ubuntu, and I want to run the last stage of my jenkinsfile forever, so I used :

```
stage("Run app service forever"){
  steps{
    withEnv(['BUILD_ID=dontKillMe']) {
      script{
        kubeconfig(credentialsId: 'my_minikube_config_file', serverUrl: 'https://###.###.###.###:8443') {
          sh 'kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 services/tecapp 5000:5000'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Jenkins last stage running forever]

NB: DON'T add **&** at the end of your command, like this :

```
stage("Run"){
  steps{
    withEnv(['BUILD_ID=dontKillMe']) {
      script{
        sh '<YOUR COMMAND HERE> &'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I used **&**, the stage didn't run forever.

Answer (score -2):

start jenkin server by

```
java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090
```

code to be in jenkinfile which goes in background

```
  stage("Starting API Server"){
    withEnv(['BUILD_ID=dontkill']) {
         sh 'mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="APPLICATION_SERVER.App" & '
        }
   }
```